# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I know there are so many similar posts for this question. I tried to implement all but not working for me. Please help me why I am getting this error java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>

I tried to implement MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
Annotation @EnableWebMvc
But not working

Do I need to include headers also to get that working? Please let me know

Code that I have written is:

Controller class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value = "/app/data", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseData> DataInquiry(
            @RequestBody RequestData requestData,
            @RequestHeader(value = Constants.ID, required = false) String transactionId) {
        //Do some action
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseData>(responseData, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

ControllerTest class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:spring/beanRefContext.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest{

    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
            Charset.forName("utf8"));

private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired 
    WebApplicationContext wac; 

ObjectMapper mapper;
    AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter adapter;
    MockHttpServletRequest request;
    MockHttpServletResponse response;

@Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Before method execution in CommonInquiryControllerTest class ");
        //this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();

        adapter = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter();
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

@Test
    public void InquiryDataTest() throws Exception, JsonProcessingException
    {
        RequestData anObject = new RequestData();

        anObject.setId("1234");
        anObject.setQualifier("someData");     

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
        ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String requestJson=ow.writeValueAsString(anObject );

        assertNotNull(anObject.getId());
        assertNotNull(anObject.getQualifier());

        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc
                .perform(post("/app/data")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(requestJson)));

            resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());

            //This will print the response JSON string
            resultActions.andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
}
```

xml Info:
beanContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:encryption="http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption 
    http://www.jasypt.org/schema/encryption/jasypt-spring3-encryption-1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:core-application-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:region-context.xml"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="somedataSourceid" jndi-name="some name" proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>  

</beans>
```

In region-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- Import this context file and pass it the requisite properties and a Data Source named dataSource -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.java.geek"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Then how this statement "resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk())" resulted true.Bzc isOk() will  Assert the response status is {@code HttpStatus.OK} (200).

Comment: Do you have this in xml? `<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>`. Share with us your config XML, because it could be a spring configuration problem, or maybe just wrong building of mocked mvc.

Comment: Can you expose a simple get method without any response and assert response status though your test case and let us know result. Bzc I see all your configuration is correct, doubt with request mapping.

Comment: shared the xml info

Comment: @Sunil, yeah ok I will check for Get Method also

Comment: I posted the issue here for Webspehre: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467769/issue-in-executing-test-cases-while-using-websphere-for-deployment                                                                         Is this the reason, I am not able to run the test successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you Enable WebMvc, you need to scan your controller to auto register controller & url mappings.component-scan scans packages to find and register beans within the application context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.xyz" />
```

I doubt component scanning is missing in your context xml.If so Add this statement in your beanRefContext.xml.